# can you can give me solution for autocomplete textview

Tags: android, json, autocompletetextview

i have try this code but not working i have to give string url.
but i have already take autocomplete textview but not working to gettext after write.

text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

```
    abc= "rajasthan";
    xml_ajax(abc);

 //xml_ajax(text.gettext.tostring)

}

public void xml_ajax(String abc) {
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
    aq.progress(R.id.progressBar1).ajax(URL, JSONObject.class, this, "getJobs");
}

public void getJobs(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {
    Arrcateg = new ArrayList<String>();
    Arrcatvalue = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (json != null) {
        Arrcatvalue.add("--Select--");
        Arrcatvalue.add("0");
        JSONArray info = null;
        try {
            info = json.getJSONArray("Native");
            if (info.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Faltu Data Founds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject info1 = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    Arrcateg.add(info1.getString("tId"));
                    Arrcatvalue.add(info1.getString("AllInOne"));
                }

                Log.d("aaa",Arrcatvalue+"");
                spinneradapterProduct = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Arrcatvalue);
                spinneradapterProduct.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                text.setAdapter(spinneradapterProduct);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"unsuccess to access",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `but not working to gettext after write` what do you really mean?

Comment: Yes its can't working yet